# Some question about subdirect product (in ring theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am learning the subdirect product of a family of rings. 
I ask some questions (true or false) to myself and I want to check the answer.

1. Is $2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ a subdirect product of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$?
2. Is $0\times \mathbb{Z}$ a subdirect product of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$?
3. Is $\langle (2, 3)\rangle$ a subdirect product of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$?
4. Let $R=R_1\times R_2\times\cdots \times R_n$ and let $S$ be a subdirect product of $R$. Then $S=R$.

> All are false. A counterexample of 4 is $\{(0, 2s), (1, 2t+1)\mid s, t\in \mathbb{Z}\}\leq \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by subdirect product? A subring inside the product ring?

Comment: Yeah. A subdirect product of $R=\prod_{i\in I}R_i$ is a subring of $R$ which satisfying that for every $k\in I$, $\pi_k(R)=R_k$, 
where $\pi_k:\prod_{i\in I}R_i\to R_k$ is the canonical epimorphism.

Comment: If you want the rings to have unital elements then 1. and 4. are clearly wrong. By 3. if you denote the *subring generated* by this element, then is correct. Though, usually by this notation we denote the principal *ideal* generated by this. 2. is correct.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Sorry. Do the "wrong" and "correct" in your comment refer to the statement or my answer?
That is, do you mean "the statement is wrong" or "my answer is wrong"?
The notation $\langle (2, 3)\rangle$ means the principle ideal generated by $(2, 3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly we had I kind of similar conversation at this thread [$R$ a ring with 1 and charac. $n>1$ (resp. 0) $\implies R$ contains a subring $\simeq \Bbb{Z}_n$ (resp. $\Bbb{Z}$). What happens if $R$ has no 1?!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343162/r-a-ring-with-1-and-charac-n1-resp-0-implies-r-contains-a-subring/2343174#2343174) where as it's been stated many questions are a kind of convention. For different people what you have written in your question may give a different answer. For me, for instance (4.) is clearly wrong (and for the others too I hope :P), since thinking $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, with the obvious ring structure, the subdirect product $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is clearly a subring, and clearly $ \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \neq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ too. Concerning the other questions now, the example (2.) is correct, since (I will go through the more categorical version since in your comment above since to adapt this) the finite direct product in category of rings (product) coincide with the finite direct sums (coproduct) (which is in fact the case for any abelian category), hence the canonical injection $i_1: 0 \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, in the coproduct definition implies (2.).

Concerning (3.) ideals in my universe of rings are not subrings (and for many others too, since the subring case is quite restrictive), hence this is false too. Your last question (1.) has to do with the way you define the subrings. If your convention wants the rings with unit, and the unit of a subring should coincide with the unit of the bigger ring inside where it lives, then the answer is false. For me $2\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a subring, is just an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, hence the product you derscribed cannot be.